# Dlib error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, uwp, linker, dlib, libpng

I'm currently trying to implement the DLIB library to my UWP application. I followed the Dlib compile instructions from http://dlib.net/compile.html. I generated the dlib project for "Windows Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" and made a Release build using CMAKE.

In the project I want to use the Dlib library I added a C++ Runtime Component project and set the following properties for the project:

- \...\dlib-19.9\source to VC++ Directories->Include Directories
- \...\dlib-19.9\build\dlib\Release to VC++ Directories->Library Directories
- dlib_release_64bit_msvc1912.lib to Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

I've also added the following Preprocessor Definitions:

```
DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT
DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT
DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT
NDEBUG
```

But now the Runtime Component project won't compile anymore and gives me the following error:

> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_ExitProcess in \...\dlib_release_64bit_msvc1912.lib(pngerror.obj)

When I remove the DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT from the Preprocessor Definitions it will compile, but of course it will say that I need to add DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT to the Preprocessor Definitions.

I have no clue how to solve this error. Am I doing something wrong or how can I solve this error?

Comment: Linker error, Have you modified `Additional Dependencies` under the `Linker` Input option?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes, I added dlib_release_64bit_msvc1912.lib to the Additional Dependencies

Comment: Have you add `Additional Library Directories` under the Linker General option?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I added \...\dlib-19.9\build\dlib\Release under `Linker->Library Directories` and \...\dlib-19.9\source under `Linker->Include Directories`

Comment: How about `Reference  Directories`? Do you change it?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT No, I did not change that one

Comment: If your project configuration correctly, please try remove `DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT` option.

Comment: I can remove `DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT` without problems. I'm only getting the linker error when I add `DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT`.

Comment: Please try follow this [blog](http://blog.csdn.net/iboxty/article/details/44780341) and re-configure your project, let me know the result.

Comment: @CoCaIceDew that blog works fine, until I want to do some image processing I need to add `DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT` which gives me the same linker error again. 
@NicoZhu-MSFT Sorry, I see I made a mistake. I added \...\dlib-19.9\build\dlib\Release under `VC++ Directories->Library Directories` and \...\dlib-19.9\source under `VC++ Directories->Include Directories`

Comment: Yep, I researched some blog, it said when use dlib.lib that compiled with cmake will throw LNK2001 error. They suggest generated dlib.lib by source compiled.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT where did you find that blog or what do you mean with _source compiled_?

Comment: Please check `Compiling C++ Examples Without CMake` where in your case link.

Comment: Have you tried to add `dlib/all/source.cpp` to your project ?

Comment: I still don't know why I'm getting the linker error when I add `DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT`, but in the end I don't need the png support, it was just for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Add `source.cpp` file from `dlib/all/source.cpp` directory.